# Unable to copy tables cross project in BigQuery web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

First time I've seen this error. BigQuery won't let me copy a table cross project via the web UI, but using the console works just fine.

Is this a bug in the web UI? It used to work.

[image]

[image]

Console works fine:

[image]

Comment: is data location same for both source and destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we introduced a UI bug in our most recent release that makes cross-project copy jobs fail.  I'm working on a fix.  Thanks for the bug report!

Comment: Any ETA on a roll-out fix?

Comment: It should arrive in early January, probably the first week or two.